# Computer Graphics degree or Game Development degree to get into game industry?

Tags: game-industry, education, career, jobs

I am currently having a BSc degree in *Computer Science*. I want to get into AAA game industry. My focus is on the core stuffs like rendering, physics, graphics programming. I plan to get a master's degree for that. Now, should I choose a broader branch, *Computer Graphics*, or should I go for the specific *Game Development* for the degree? 
Note: It maybe easier for me to get the Computer Graphics degree. And I know that I have to show some complete projects, practical knowledge, passions to get the job in the industry.

Comment: [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net) has a Career Development forum that you could ask this in.

Comment: This type of questions had been asked and answered here before!

Comment: They have been considered off-topic here for years. Just because they were acceptable in the sites early years or that one or two may have slipped by the community's notice in the interim does not make them on topic today, I'm afraid.